# Removing hover effects on touch devices css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've seen this question a few times but nothing seems to work for what I'm looking for.

I need to keep my `:hover` effects in my stylesheet as I have a few on Desktop. As soon as I hit `900px` I want to remove them.

Is there a way to remove a hover so for example, on some elements on hover I change the opacity. Am I able to do

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .my_element:hover {
    opacity: none:
  }
}
```

So on mobile/touch screen devices the change in opacity on hover is default.

Comment: opacity can take only 3 values: number(0..1), initial, inherit and on phones and tablets hover don't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the correct default value for opacity.  The default value is `opacity:1`.  You can look up the default values using MDN (or whatever other resource, but MDN usually has it front and center) like so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

---

Another option is to set it to `initial`.  That would make the rule `opacity: initial;`. (Note that this is [not supported in IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=initial), but it is supported in edge)

---

Lastly, you could consider instead placing your hover values in an opposite media query.  For your example this would be the following:

I've seen this question a few times but nothing seems to work for what I'm looking for.

I need to keep my :hover effects in my stylesheet as I have a few on Desktop. As soon as I hit 900px I want to remove them.

Is there a way to remove a hover so for example, on some elements on hover I change the opacity. Am I able to do

```
@media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
  .my_element:hover {
    /* your hover state style rules */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is definitely the better method. I was just thinking of trying to prevent the `:hover` effects on mobile quickly by maybe just adding `none` but this is very quick and works.

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st You're welcome.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse your logic, using a mobile first approach, instead adding your hover effects at 900px. i.e. (min-width: 900px)

Comment: Yup, thanks man. Joseph suggested the same. This is what I've opted for and works. It's always quick to just throw my `:hover` styles into a media query

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way (as far as I know) to simply remove every hover effect. You will have to reset the individual effects each hover applies.

However, I would like to mention that doing this is in most cases not necessary. For touch devices, no hover effect should be present, as there is no cursor to hover with. Just leave it be and consider it impossible to reach.